# Node + Mongodb + sort nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using node with mongodb.I try to sort nested array.

Example json in monogodb.

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "A",
            "order": 3
        }, {
            "name": "B",
            "order": 2
        }, {
            "name": "C",
            "order": 1
        }, {
            "name": "D",
            "order": 4
        }
    ],
    "name": "Test",
        "_id" : 01245678913
}
{
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "A",
            "order": 3
        }, {
            "name": "B",
            "order": 2
        }, {
            "name": "C",
            "order": 1
        }, {
            "name": "D",
            "order": 4
        }
    ],
    "name": "Test",
        "_id" : 098765432134
}
```

I am expecting result should display based on order. items.order

Here possible to pass ID. If get Id means display the result for the respective Id. otherwise need to show all lists.

I attached my node code:

```
router.post('/get', function(req, res, next) {

        var results = {
            resp : {},
            id : null,
            query : {}
        };

        if (!( typeof req.body['id'] === 'undefined' || req.body['id'] === null )) {
            results.id = req.body['id'];
        }

        Q(results).then(function(results) {
            var deferred = Q.defer();
            var collection = mongoUtil.list;
            if (results.id != null) {
                results.query._id = ObjectId(results.id);
            }


            collection.find(results.query).toArray(function(err, lists) {

                if (!err && lists.length > 0) {
                    results.resp.lists = lists;
                    deferred.resolve(results);
                } else {

                    results.resp.message = 'No List';
                    results.resp.debug = err;
                    deferred.reject(results);
                }
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }).then(function(results) {
            results.resp.message = 'Result found';
            results.resp.status = 'Success';
            res.send(results.resp);
        }).fail(function(results) {
            results.resp.status = 'Error';
            res.send(results.resp);
        });

    });
```

I found few example they using aggregate function.

```
collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$answers"}, 
  {$sort: {"item.order":1}}, 
  {$group: {_id:"$_id", answers: {$push:"$answers"}}}
]);
```

Here little bit confusing.

Comment: The `aggregate` you are suggesting looks good to me. What went wrong?

Comment: The above code not working for me. ====>>>>                collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$answers"}, 
  {$sort: {"item.order":1}}, 
  {$group: {_id:"$_id", answers: {$push:"$answers"}}}
]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Aggregations** operations process data records and return computed results. Aggregation operations group values from multiple documents together, and can perform a variety of operations on the grouped data to return a single result.

**Try this -**

```
collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$items" },
  { $sort: { "items.order": 1 } },
  { $group: { _id: "$_id", items: { $push: "$items" } } }
]);
```

> **db.collection.aggregate(pipeline, options):-**  Calculates aggregate values for the data in a collection.
>
> **Pipeline $unwind (aggregation) stage:-** Deconstructs an array field from the input documents to output a document for each element.
>   Each output document is the input document with the value of the array
>   field replaced by the element.
>
> > *Examples-*
> >
> > Consider an inventory items with the following document:
> >
> > `{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC1", sizes: [ "S", "M", "L"] }`
>
> The following aggregation uses the $unwind stage to output a document
>   for each element in the sizes array:
>
> > `db.items.aggregate( [ { $unwind : "$sizes" } ] )`
> >
> > The operation returns the following results:
> >
> > `{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC1", "sizes" : "S" } { "_id" : 1, "item" :
> >     "ABC1", "sizes" : "M" } { "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC1", "sizes" : "L" }`
>
> **Pipeline $sort (aggregation) stage:-** Sorts all input documents and
>   returns them to the pipeline in sorted order.
>
> The $sort stage has the following prototype form:
>
> `{ $sort: { <field1>: <sort order>, <field2>: <sort order> ... } }`
>
> > *Examples-*
> >
> > For the field or fields to sort by, set the sort order to 1 or -1 to
> >     specify an ascending or descending sort respectively, as in the
> >     following example:
> >
> > `db.users.aggregate(    [
> >         { $sort : { age : -1, posts: 1 } }    ] )`
>
> **Pipeline $group (aggregation) stage:-** Groups documents by some
>   specified expression and outputs to the next stage a document for each
>   distinct grouping. The output documents contain an _id field which
>   contains the distinct group by key. $group does not order its output
>   documents.
>
> The $group stage has the following prototype form:
>
> `{ $group: { _id: <expression>, <field1>: { <accumulator1> :
>   <expression1> }, ... } }`
>
> > > *Accumulator $push:-* Returns an array of all values that result from
> > >       applying an expression to each document in a group of documents that
> > >       share the same group by key.
> > >
> > > $push has the following syntax:
> > >
> > > `{ $push: <expression> }`
> > >
> > > $push is only available in the $group stage.

For more reference see this link - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/

Comment: @RSKMR, I hope this will clear your confusion a little bit.