# node.js+mongodb sorting nested array is not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am not able to sort the nested array. I have referred many links such as [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37065869/node-mongodb-sort-nested-array) but still I haven't got proper solution for my problem.

Here is my JSON data:

```
{
  _id: "5a8bf7e3903cc83237ebd014",
  prospect_name: "Akruthi",
  phone: "9878979879",
  email: "",
  address: "Kundapur",
  landmark: "Grt",
  city: "Udupi",
  state: "5a869c795eb34ecae3ab1ef6",
  region: "5a8689725eb34ecae3ab1ede",
  methodology: 2,
  sub_category: "colour",
  created_by: "asdadasad",
  referred_by: "Self",
  remarks: [
          {
            data: "Good",
            user: "5a8c0642903cc83237ebd01f",
            created_at: "2018-02-20T10:26:43.686Z",
            remarksId: "5a8bf7e3903cc83237ebd013",
          },
          {
            data: "test 1",
            user: "5a858129e6e8f6724d6aa551",
            created_at: "2018-02-21T04:35:30.615Z",
            remarksId: "5a8cf7122ad6f00da98a3f05",
          },
          {
            data: "test 2",
            user: "5a858129e6e8f6724d6aa551",
            created_at: "2018-02-21T04:41:45.514Z",
            remarksId: "5a8cf889160046121e3f1b25",
          },
          {
            data: "test 3",
            user: "5a858129e6e8f6724d6aa551",
            created_at: "2018-02-21T04:54:01.018Z",
            remarksId: "5a8cfb69ea4e7c14c1f7c550",
          },
         ],
  created_at: "2018-02-20T10:26:43.686Z"
}
```

I have done the following query in node.js:

```
return collection_name
 .aggregate([
                { $match: { _id: objectid(id) } },
                { $lookup: { from: 'state', localField: 'state', foreignField: '_id', as: 'state_details' } },
                { $lookup: { from: 'region', localField: 'region', foreignField: '_id', as: 'region_details' } },
                { $lookup: { from: 'users', localField: 'remarks.user', foreignField: '_id', as: 'remarks_details' } },
                { $unwind: '$remarks' },
                { $sort: { 'remarks.created_at': -1 } },
                { $group: { _id: '$_id', remarks: { $push: '$remarks' } } },
            ])
```

and I got result as: (got the sorted result, but lost other fields)

```
{
 _id: "5a8bf7e3903cc83237ebd014",
 remarks: [
        {
          data: "test 3",
          user: "5a858129e6e8f6724d6aa551",
          created_at: "2018-02-21T04:54:01.018Z",
          remarksId: "5a8cfb69ea4e7c14c1f7c550"
        },
        {
          data: "test 2",
          user: "5a858129e6e8f6724d6aa551",
          created_at: "2018-02-21T04:41:45.514Z",
          remarksId: "5a8cf889160046121e3f1b25"
        },
        {
          data: "test 1",
          user: "5a858129e6e8f6724d6aa551",
          created_at: "2018-02-21T04:35:30.615Z",
          remarksId: "5a8cf7122ad6f00da98a3f05"
        },
        {
          data: "Good",
          user: "5a8c0642903cc83237ebd01f",
          created_at: "2018-02-20T10:26:43.686Z",
          remarksId: "5a8bf7e3903cc83237ebd013"
        }
         ]
}
```

In my result I lost all the other fields except **remarks**. I wanted the result along with other fields as well.. I tried `$project` operation but still it did not work.

**expected result:**

```
    {
  _id: "5a8bf7e3903cc83237ebd014",
  prospect_name: "Akruthi",
  phone: "9878979879",
  email: "",
  address: "Kundapur",
  landmark: "Grt",
  city: "Udupi",
  state: "5a869c795eb34ecae3ab1ef6",
  region: "5a8689725eb34ecae3ab1ede",
  methodology: 2,
  sub_category: "colour",
  created_by: "asdadasad",
  referred_by: "Self",
  remarks: [
          {
          data: "test 3",
          user: "5a858129e6e8f6724d6aa551",
          created_at: "2018-02-21T04:54:01.018Z",
          remarksId: "5a8cfb69ea4e7c14c1f7c550"
        },
        {
          data: "test 2",
          user: "5a858129e6e8f6724d6aa551",
          created_at: "2018-02-21T04:41:45.514Z",
          remarksId: "5a8cf889160046121e3f1b25"
        },
        {
          data: "test 1",
          user: "5a858129e6e8f6724d6aa551",
          created_at: "2018-02-21T04:35:30.615Z",
          remarksId: "5a8cf7122ad6f00da98a3f05"
        },
        {
          data: "Good",
          user: "5a8c0642903cc83237ebd01f",
          created_at: "2018-02-20T10:26:43.686Z",
          remarksId: "5a8bf7e3903cc83237ebd013"
        }
         ],
  created_at: "2018-02-20T10:26:43.686Z"
}
```

Comment: try $$root to get all fields.

Comment: can u give example of `$root`

Comment: I have updated comment. plz check

Comment: yeah can you give me `$$root` example with my query please. I have never tried `$$root` before

Comment: refer this    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23011193/using-root-in-aggregation-order

Comment: yes I have referred and followed the same method.. but result will be multiple.. for each remarks, each separate record will be displayed.

Comment: in one record for one Id, under remarks all the data should be displayed with sorted by date. as I shown above as expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add
{ 
$project:{
 prospect_name: 1,
  phone: 1,
  email: 1,
  address: 1,
  landmark: 1,
  city: 1,
  state: 1,
  region: 1,
  methodology: 1,
  sub_category: 1,
  created_by: 1,
  referred_by: 1
}
}
and  replace your group by query with following line
 { $group: { _id: null, remarks: { $push: '$remarks' } } }